# How can I find which country offers the best income to expense ratio?

Tags: data-request, living-cost

Some countries offer good earning, but some of them also have high taxes and living expenses.

How can I find which country offers the best income to expense ratio?

Is there any index available?

Comment: The best bet is to check the World Bank group database . 
 Here is one table that might be interesting. 
  https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.XPN.COMP.ZS

Comment: Is this a [Money.SE] question? If it is, you probably don't want economic data, but something that is specific to your job/potential target city/standard of living.

Comment: It is a very generous bounty but I second Giskard. What have you tried so far? A quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=income+to+expense+ratio+countries) seems fairly useful? Although a proper comparison is certainly tricky, as it really depends on the area and data you care about. Some countries are very diverse (Mississippi vs California for example). Also, apart from expenses, I assume it would make sense to consider accessibility and quality of things that people need (health care, houses, infrastructure,...).  In the end, price is what you pay, value is what you get.

Answer (score 4):

I think "Jones, C. I., & Klenow, P. J. (2016). Beyond GDP? Welfare across countries and time. American Economic Review." is the paper you are looking for. In particular the following figure (the full data is in Jones' website):

[image]